# Why don't cyclists wear all-encompassing motorcycle-style helmets?

Tags: safety, helmets

It is possible to get a helmet that covers your entire head and face, and in theory would protect you against more kinds of falls. In particular, Why don't bicyclists wear them, and why *do* motorcyclists wear them?

I'm not asking whether helmets are a good idea in general. (Please try to answer this with *complete* answers, rather than the single-point style of the currently running helmet thread.)

Comment: Take a look at this [Google Image search](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&source=imghp&biw=1366&bih=668&q=mountain+bike+full+face+helmet&gbv=2&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) for an idea of what bike full face helmets look it. Difference with moto helmet is that they're lighter (impacts come at much slower speeds) and more vented.

Comment: An equally good question would be "do top-of-head helmets actually do anything?" Both the last couple of times I've come off my bike I've landed on my face, the only thing saving me being my arms. I find it hard to imagine a situation where I'd land on the top/back of my head...

Comment: Cost-benefit ratio.

Comment: I've seen a *lot* of bike crashes in my years and have always wondered this too.  Out of all those crashes, I've only seen one head impact to the ground and had one myself.  All the rest the people used their arms to instinctively protect the head.  In the one I witnessed, the helmet was completely ineffective as it was a face plant.  Mine was also a face plant, but I had no helmet on.  given the impact location, a helmet would have been equally useless for me.

Comment: Do you also wear a full face helmet every time you walk stairs? It is proven that walking stairs is more dangerous than cycling. http://www.aviewfromthecyclepath.com/2011/03/stairs-are-dangerous-wear-helmet.html

Comment: If your bike helmet is tilted too far back it will not protect your face when sucking mud.  The brim and sweatband should be on the skin of your forehead, not on your hair.   If your visor limits your vision, remove the visor.

Comment: Also see https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30099/is-it-practical-to-wear-motorcycle-half-helmet-for-road-cycling

Answer (score 80):

Some bicyclists do wear full-face helmets; in particular, downhill mountain bikers and BMXers will frequently wear full-face helmets, as the chance of a crash causing you to land on your face is greater.

The problem with full-face helmets is that they're hotter; your head is great for getting rid of excess heat, and the full-face helmet helps trap more of that in. Motorcyclists aren't pedaling furiously, and don't need to lose as much heat; heat management is essential for bicycling.

Furthermore, motorcycle accidents tend to happen at higher speeds. On a bike, you're pretty unlikely to wipe out at 60 MPH, while on a motorcycle, it's all too possible. Between the lower risk on a bike, the heat issues, and the extra cost of full-face helmets, for most people it's not worth it to wear the full face helmet on their bicycle.

Any safety feature is a trade-off, between the costs of implementing the feature and the harm or damage that it prevents. When the cost of implementing the feature exceed the expected value of the feature in harm reduction (taking into account the likelihood of the particular form of accident happening, and how severe the damage is), then it doesn't make sense to use that feature. People all assign different values to certain types of harm or damage, and also have different risks based on how they ride and what their environment is like. For some people, wearing a full-face helmet may be worth the extra expense and heat, but most people don't find it's worth that trade-off.

Sadly, for many of these decisions, we don't have enough information; there isn't very much conclusive real-world data on the efficacy of bike helmets, let alone different types of bike helmets.

Comment: they are a lot more expensive as well.

Comment: Also you can't hear anything wearing motorbike helmets and your vision is very limited.

Comment: Your vision is limited when wearing a motorbike helmet but when I am on my motorbike I can easily hear cars/vans approaching behind me (i guess it depends on the quality of the helmet), the limited field of view is also why in the UK you are taught "Lifesaver" checks - which really should be used when riding bicycles too.

Comment: Are there cycling helmets with mouth guards (similar to an American football helmet)?  That would allow airflow while protecting the jaw and nose.  I ask because when I crashed my bike (albeit without a helmet back in those days) I landed squarely on my jaw, requiring 12 stitches.

Comment: @mskfisher - yes look at mountain biking helmets, they have a chin guard for this very reason.

Comment: @Mauro, yes learning to ride a motorbike is the best training for riding a bicycle - especially in cities.  Only problem is I moved across the pond and I can't get out of the habit of doing a lifesaver over my RIGHT shoulder.

Comment: @Mauro "which really should be used when riding bicycles too": Indeed they should. (And many do.) But of course looking over your shoulder with a helmet on is far less effective, due to the limited field of vision, than looking over your shoulder without one. I consider a comparison between helmet + safety checks and no helmet + no safety checks to be unfair; the helmet and the checks are independent. Also consider that on a motorcycle, you have mirrors, so direct field of vision is less important.

Comment: I would add to this [the answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1743/why-dont-cyclists-wear-all-encompassing-motorcycle-style-helmets/1856#1856) @David HAust wrote -- hearing is more important on a bicycle, and such helmets can limit your hearing.

Comment: I mostly do MTB, little road bike and everyday commuting in a road motorbike. I wouldn't imagine using my motorbike helmet (even if it was a MX style one) when using the bike. Besides its weight and narrow field of vision I think it would also be somewhat claustrophobic, not letting you breathe properly when doing exercise at a high intensity.

Comment: @NarcísCalvet You've clearly never worn a proper DH lid then; they're very lightweight, have plenty of airflow, and MTB/MX googles have a wider FOV than road motorbike visors.

Comment: @cbamber85 I did. My DH experience is very limited but I used a DH helmet. I wouldn't even consider using one for XC or road cycling though. Even they are breathable and light enough for DH, in my opinion, they aren't enough for those disciplines.

Comment: @mgb you can hear just as well as with a regular bicycle helmet, especially with a dirtbike helmet or something similar

Comment: I disagree with the whole 'you get hot' thing, as many mtb helmet come with up to 30 vents and dirtbike helmets also have a large number vents. I use my dirtbike helmet to road bike as well as mtb, and I notice little to no difference in heat.

Comment: Motorcyclists are not only not pedaling, but they are moving through the air at 50, 60, 80, 100+ km/h.  That's a lot of wind chill; the helmet helps them stay warm.

Comment: @Mauro If your side peripheral vision is in any way impaired by a motorcycle helmet, the helmet either doesn't fit you, or is unfit for purpose and should never be used. There is some limitation of vertical FOV however.

Comment: @mgb If you're on a Harley Davidson (or similar), the only thing you can hear is your own ride anyway.

Answer (score 27):

You also have to consider that a motorcycle has no trouble accelerating to and maintaining traffic speeds.  In short, a motorcycle really doesn't need to look backward with anywhere near the frequency that a cyclist does.  They also have mirrors mounted on their bikes which most cyclists don't have.

For example.  Coming off a red light, anyone on a motorcycle can just go without consideration for anything behind them.  Lane changes require major planning on a bicycle, but are relatively simple on a motorcycle traveling at matching speeds with all the cars.

Comment: Even with traffic speed one should know what happens behind. Mirrors, of course, allow doing that almost unconsciously ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Due to momentum, people in bicycle collisions tend to fall forward in the direction they were moving.  Therefore, they often land on their faces, which are entirely unprotected by standard bicycle helmets.

I speak from experience, having just lost all of my top front teeth.  My surgeon says this is incredibly common among urban bike commuters.

There is no demand for full face helmets for cyclists because people are socialized to think that (1) they're overkill and (2) they look silly.

I sure wish I was wearing a full-face helmet when I crashed.  And no preaching about safe riding!  I am a strong city rider, who errs on the side of caution when it comes to safety.  Collisions do happen.

Comment: I think you're way off. I too have landed on my face and knocked out my front teeth during a bicycle accident but I don't wear a full face helmet. It has nothing to do with socialization or looking silly. Safety features are a trade off. The more protected you are, the hotter you are. In the summer it's often over 100 degrees where I live. Heat exhaustion is a real possibility almost every day. A full face helmet would only make it worse.

Comment: "(1) its overkill and (2) it looks silly" - For a lot of people, it's exactly that. If it would be the heat exhaustion, you would at least see some people try it - but they don't, because it looks silly. I had the same experience with skiing helmets: I don't do big jumps, I don't ski very fast, over here for the most part only children wear them, so it would look silly for me to have one. Then I went to Switzerland and suddenly I was (nearly) the only one on the hill not to wear one. Next season, I'll give them a try.

Comment: Pedestrians can and do lose front teeth when they trip over too. This is why full face helmets make as much sense for walking as they do for cycling. It also solves the "where do I leave the helmet when I lock the bike up" problem.

Comment: In general anywhere that a helmet, or a full face helmet, would help cyclists it would help far more pedestrians and motorists. One of the most dramatic wins from wearing a helmet is in the shower, but I don't see "shower helmets" on the market. The trade-offs just aren't right for those, or for motorist helmets. But you do see people wit intellectual handicaps who are prone to falls wearing them... I think it's because they lack autonomy, so "it will make you safer" overrides "it's stupid".

Answer (score 11):

In [this recent blog post](http://cyclelondoncity.blogspot.com/2010/10/english-streets-are-too-old-and-small.html), the author (not me, I just subscribe to their feed) indirectly addresses your question:

> My grandmother used to cycle about in a skirt when we were in Germany together. She wasn't very fast. Actually, I'd say she was about as fast as a very small hamster, or thereabouts. I don't think she was pretending to be a motorbike. But she liked it that way. In fact, she  used to cycle in England too. But then again, so did all her friends.
>
> Funnily enough, she never liked to cycle in England in her later years. Precisely because in England, people expected her to behave like a motorbike. She thought helmets daft. She also resented having to dress up like a belisha beacon just because our streets feel like 'spaghetii junction' (her words not mine). I think she saw herself as, well, herself. Just an old lady on a bicycle. And, frankly, her revs weren't what they used to be. So the chances of her pedalling along at the same speed as a Ducati were fairly slim.

I don't wear a full-face, whole-head helmet because I've weighed up the risks and I don't need one. I'm not a motorcyclist, I don't have to confront the same dangers a motorbike rider does.

Full-head helmets for bikes are available, so where there's a demand, there is a supply.

Answer (score 11):

I do always wear a full face (downhill) helmet on my everyday (25 km one way) commute to the job. Being a downhill addict, it's been straightforward to put it on from home to my training sites and back. Since this was quite manageable, I skipped the half-face helmet completely even for normal cycling some three years ago.

Yes, full face helmets get hotter than bike helmets. Still, downhill helmets stay much cooler than motocross ones. Also, ventilation has improved a lot over the last years. Anyway, this is mostly a question of getting used to. Here, the summer is usually between 20 and 25 °C, and it's not a problem. In winter (between -10 and -20 °C), I use my motocross helmet to stay warm. At least I skip these funny tower constructions - trying to press-fit a scarf and a fur cap under a traditional bike helmet. :)

Yes, you get the looks. Feeling observed... huh?   This is merely a question of carrying a large pink teddybear across a populated city square. Do it five times and this part is over.

Yes, there is a certain reduction of the field of view. Place a tiny mirror on your bike frame.

Hearing is not at all impeded by a downhill helmet but considerably reduced when wearing a motocross or other mc helmet, specially directional hearing. So you need to look twice!

One and a half year ago one of my colleagues had a face plant and got a quite painful chin surgery, and also lost 3 teeth that had to be re-implanted. Needless to say - he's joined the club by now.

Answer (score 6):

When riding in traffic/city areas, your ears are almost as important as your eyes for keeping safe.  And wearing a full face motorbike style helmet would severely limit your hearing.

Add that to the excellent points Brian and Meagar make above about full face helmets being hot and heavy.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it goes more towards full face helmets in the future.  The world is heading away from prevention and more towards mitigation as the primary safety strategy.

Comment: I'd say ears are more important in some circumstances, as your can only see where you're looking but you can hear everything, including the Audi/BMW/White Van driver barrelling up behind you with no intention of giving you any clearance when they pass you.

Answer (score 6):

I think that it's ridiculous that bicyclists wear so little protection.  I fell recently doing 20 miles an hour and broke my collarbone, damaged my shoulder and busted open my chin--all while wearing a dinky helmet.  I've concluded that a 15-25 mile bicycle crash is all that it takes to do permanent damage.

I began to wonder why my motorcycle friends wear more protective gear and I don't.  They wear better helmets, shoulder pads, chaps, etc all to protect them from road rash and more severe injuries.  Bicyclists go out half naked but travel at only slightly slower speeds that motorcyclists around urban streets.

**ANSWER:: I've concluded that bicyclists are less protected because there are no role models for being more protected.**

Nowhere do you see Professionals in pads and a better helmet.  When every cyclist that you see in print and video is shown unprotected, the rest of us poseurs become too embarrassed to wear protective garb.  The message from the media and professionals is "Man Up. Ride Unprotected."

Comment: Same with passengers in vehicles, Michael Schumacher wears a helmet, facemask, neckbrace and fireproof overalls - but almost nobody on the bus does.

Comment: In your case, I'm with the media.  Cowboy up, dude.

Comment: As Ghandi said, "be the change you want to see in the world". I don't think he promised that it would change, and I'd have a bit to say if someone tried to convince me to wear my motorbike gear on a pushbike...

Comment: In what kind of weather do you ride?  Do you often cycle in 80°F (25°C) weather wearing an unvented helmet, leather jacket, and chaps?

Comment: I'd like to meet your cycling friends who travel "at only slightly slower speeds than motorcyclists."  Any of them named Lance?

Comment: In the city many motorcylists travel at the same speed as other motorists... 10-15kph.

Comment: I agree with you as long as it is about down hill or high numbers of cyclists in a competition cycing. NOT for quiet spins to the shops.

Comment: as someone who has ridden bikes for over 25 years, both road and mountain. i've had my fair share of falls, and i've never felt that i need full padding. not many people put an importance on learning how to fall.  which is almost more important that just wearing protective gear. personally i've never hit my head on the ground, but i still wear my helmet.

Answer (score 4):

Some cyclists do, specifically in the types of cycling that are more prone to falls, or where falling into obstacles like trees are more likely. Specifically, down-hill or BMX style helmets usually cover parts of the face.

Typically, motorcycle helmets and full-face bicycling helmets are hotter and heavier, making them less well suited for exercise or strenuous activity. Conversely cycling helmets meant for on-road use are extremely light weight and usually contain a large number of holes allowing airflow to evaporate sweat and cool the wearer, while providing good protection for falls on flat pavement.

So unless you have a specific *need* for additoinal protection, "all-encompassing motorcycle-style" helmets generally not worn.

Comment: -1 There are many different types of motorcycle helmet (just like bicycle helmets), the one you're thinking of (road motorcycle) is but one - just about every over type _is_ for stenous activity.

Answer (score 4):

All the points mentioned above are true and mostly all-encompassing. Here's my take on the point.

I am a biker and motorcyclist, both. I have biker helmet and full face 1.2kg heavy motorcycling helmet, which becomes a half face helmet too when needed.

[image: Half Face]

[image: Full Face]

On one occasion I did wear the motorcycle helmet during a leisure cycle ride in the city. I don't mind the looks other commuters gave me. Yes it did hamper the listening a little bit, but not much since I am used to wearing full face helmet on my motorcycle and yet can listen to brake and horn sounds clearly over the din of the exhaust.

The only issue that I faced was - Severe neck-ache within a short span of 30 minutes which never happens during motorcycle ride. The reason for this is body posture and movement. During cycle ride, your whole body moves with every pedal movement. From head to toe. The lightweight cycle helmet does not feel like an additional weight on the neck. Also your body posture keeps on changing rapidly - from straight up at crossroads to bending over to gain speed. All this time with cycle helmet you do not have to worry weight since its barely weighs anything (as compared to motorcycle helmet). The ride with motorcycle helmet became a sore neck (literally) since every movement you do, pedalling, bending forward, is accompanied by massive continuously shifting weight on the neck.

The neck-ache does not happen in motorcycle because for most of the ride, you are sitting in almost the same position. Your body movements are limited to hand and feet movement from braking, accelerating and gear changes. This does not involve whole body motion and hence once the helmet is set in for the ride, additional stress is not felt.

Side Note - Helmet stress can be felt on long motorcycle rides (3-4 hours long continous rides, not taking terrain into consideration. If you do take bumpy and uneven road, that time comes down drastically)

Comment: This answers "why don't bicycle riders wear motorbike helmets", which I don't think is actually the question - full face bicycle helmets are available and don't have most of the issues you identify with motorbike helmets.

Comment: @Moz Point taken.

Answer (score 2):

I had a regular mountain bike half helmet for mountain biking, and never had problems... then, one day I crashed hard (due to unexpected hikers on the single track going downhill) and fell on my face: almost knocking out my front 4 teeth, and nice scrapes and bruises on my nose and chin (not cool to have on a girl).

I've recovered with some scarring, but the fall made me realize that they made the full-faced helmet for a GREAT REASON.  I used to think it looked heavy and ridiculous, but now I use the full-face for going downhill, and switch out to the half helmet on my climbs back up.  Safety first!

By the way, I bought a rockgarden full-face helmet, and it's very comfy and has lots of ventilation.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles.SE! Thank you for your contribution. Your post contains useful content, but the lack of punctuation and capitalization make it hard to read. Please use the "edit" link to fix your post. And again, welcome to the site!

Comment: You carry two helmets on rides? Wow. Unfortunately a couple of the face-damaging falls I've seen happened in carparks, people who had assembled their bikes but failed to tighten the front wheel properly so at the first bump it fell off. The full face helmet only protects you while you're wearing it.

Comment: @Móż There are convertible helmets with a detachable chin section. I imagine they're less protective than a permanent chin, but still better than direct ground impact. It is unclear whether the Answerer is using a convertible or brings two helmets on rides.

Answer (score 0):

Because the bicycle industry markets riding a bicycle as a sport with everything specific. Just look at what a motor vehicle does to a little Styrofoam helmet in crashes. I opted for a 3/4 face motorcycle helmet that has a flip down shield and removable chin bar. Its well vented, plenty light and has an excellent field of view. If commuting among traffic than be professional and wear adequate hi-vis, protective gear. Someone didn't figure all this out already, its truly up to bicycle commuters of today to set the standards of tomorrow!

Comment: If it's just about being bicycle-specific, why don't manufacturers make "bicycle-specific" full-face helmets for road cyclists?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Looks like a year after you asked, [someone is trying it](https://bikerumor.com/ventoux-cycling-helmet-concept-aims-for-aero-full-face-road-riding-protection/).

Answer (score 0):

I live in a small town that has alot of through traffic passing by cars and heavy oversized rigs, I ride a MTB with a mirror almost every day on the road to do my every day needs. ;) After having a car reverse out infront of/ into me 6 weeks ago, I've just ordered 2 full face (Predator) helmets 1 white for daytime, 1 black for night. Because forcibly face planting into rear windows on cars ISN'T a pleasant experience!! I don't care if people might think it will look weird! I'd rather the protection and it might make me more noticeable to the drivers too which can only be a good thing!! ;) I have large panniers on my bike so helmet storage isn't an issue! ;) once the new helmets arrive, Ill see what the ventilation is like and may have to just use normal bike helmets on 40+C days if needed. Otherwise, I'll be wearing the new full face motorbike helmets from now on!!! Yo hell with what others think it looks like! It's NOT their face and head at risk! ;)

Comment: Sorry to hear about your bad experience and good luck with the new helmets. Unfortunately, though, your post doesn't answer the question. On the other hand, once you've been riding with these helmets for a while, coming back and posting about that experience (either "I tried this and it's fine; issues XYZ that people raised weren't a problem" or "Now I've tried this, I agree with all the reasons given" or anything in between) would be really useful. Thanks!

Comment: Why not white all the time for added visibility over a black helmet ?   Feel free to edit that reply into the answer.   Can you say why you didn't want to wear one before your collision?

Comment: Its two years later - how have you found the experience riding with a full helmet ?  Use [edit] to extend your answer with updated info.

Answer (score -1):

I have read answers to this question and many of you think about bicycle accidents as if they were at lower speeds, instead of the higher speeds of motorized vehicles. I would agree with that, if you are assuming there are no motorcycles or cars around, when you ride.

However, cycling in a city exposes you to motorcycles, cars, buses and trucks in addition to other bicycles and to rear, frontal and sideways crashes with these vehicles. Apart from bicycles, motorized vehicles have speeds exceeding 20km/h and masses far greater than both bicycle and rider. Thus, protection for city riders must be in accordance with this fact.

The problem here is not velocity, but momentum and kinetic energy. Have you ever wonder why a lot of motorized vehicle accidents are fatal? They are fatal, because in this crashes there are transfers of large amounts of kinetic energy upon impact, which results in deformation --- that crushes your bones --- and throw of your body by several meters from the crash point, for example. And, of course, bicycles (and motorcycles) do not offer a lot of protection against these (in fact they suffer a lot of damage or are completely torn apart).

As any city rider must be aware of his/her surroundings in order to lower risks, it is also true that he/she must be prepared for situations that are away from his/her control. Protection provided by standard bicycle helmets will not be enough, when we would be exposed to an unavoidable collision with a motorized vehicle. I prefer to suffer from bulkier and heavier helmet like those of closed motorcycle helmets.

Comment: Hi and welcome to bicycles.stackexchange. Yours is a thoughtful answer and you've explained your reasoning well. But unfortunately I'm not convinced that motor vehicles travel especially fast on city roads shared with cyclists, or that a full face helmet will be much better than a conventional one in such a collision. Can you link to research showing either of those things? My experience is that for those collisions prevention is better than mitigation, so I'd rather spend money on lights, bright clothing, and reflectors.

Comment: There are studies around that show that riding city streets with a helmet hightens your chances on accidents where death is a common result. On the other hand, in the Netherlands many cyclists share roads with cars within cities and the countryside and almost nobody uses a helmet, even less a motorcycling one, and brain injuries are rare, broken necks are rare as well. Proof enough for me not to start wearing any helmet, even less a motor one.

Comment: Well, I will definitely say that this has relation to traffic education of the drivers. However in Mexico City, we lack of this culture. Persons can drive without passing a minimum driving examination. Unless our most recent traffic regulations prioritize pedestrians and bicycles over motor vehicles, the reality is that driving here in Mexico City is not secure, even if you take all preventive measures you can imagine. It is great that you are riding in such secure environment.

Comment: I want to say that I don't want each rider on the planet wear helmet or motorcycle helmet. I share with you, the reasoning behind my decision to wear a motorcycle helmet.

Comment: This is a personal decision based on my knowledge of physics and being witness of at least ten fatal accidents. However, I can say a thing against probabilities. You can say that the ocurrence of brain and other life-threatening injuries are low. However, that doesn't mean that you will not be the next suffering that rare ocurrence.

Comment: I know it's an old question but this is important: @Willeke there are plenty of cycle deaths in the Netherlands, in fact most deadly accidents (40%) are cyclist as compared to other types of transportation (cars 30%, and so on). 300 people die each year cycling. Source: https://swov.nl/nl/factsheet/verkeersdoden-nederland

Comment: @Ivana, most cycle deaths that are not over 70's are not head wound related. And my argument is not deaths, it is about people in hospital with brain damage that would have been prevented by a cycle helmet and there are very few of those but people who believe what the helmet promotors say will not believe any counter argument.

Answer (score -2):

One reason is that in many places the law requires motorcycle helmets to be full-face. On a bicycle in most locations helmets are not required and the choice is yours.

I ride with a half-head helmet in temperatures up to 95°F and never find ventilation is an issue at all. I can't believe the extra protection of my mouth and chin would suddenly change that.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @David. This site is different - it's not a discussion (although you can use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome) for that). Please see the [help] for how the site works.

Comment: One reason this answer has been flagged is because it is "chatty" and formatted like a question. I'll make an attempt at editing you answer; check it out as a guide, and make sure I have retained your meaning. In the meantime for an intro to how this and other Stack Exchange Q & A sites work, please [Take the Tour](https://$SITEURL$/tour).

Answer (score -4):

Motorcyclists use full face helmets because the 'happy biker with bugs on his teeth' experience.
The speed most motorcyclists go makes that they get bugs and other things in their faces at quite high forces. As they have to wear helmets, (in most countries compulsory,) they might as well add the face protection part.
At the speed they go, there is enough cooling from the air.

Most cyclist go at much lower speeds, the bugs are not that much of a danger, although at every speed they can be a nuicance.
The cooling factor of speed is much lower.
Those cyclist that mostly wear helmets have a very awkward head position, anything that makes it harder to look up will endanger the cyclist rather than protect.

On top of that, for many cyclists helmets are more precieved safety, not real life, the current helmets are enough to believe in the fairytale, nothing else is needed.

I have seen enough proof to not believe in that story and would not don any helmet, even less one that fully encloses my head.
One of the good things of cycling is the fresh clean air around my head, no way I will put a plastic case around it. A pair of glasses (and a shawl in front of my mouth in case of very nasty bugs) is all protection I need.

Comment: This was a good answer until the anti helmet rant started. - 1.

Comment: why @NeilFein ? I think he is right cyclist helmets fall apart from a heavy rain they don't protect your face or back head or side .... they don't even protect you if something fall over your head (being that feeble and having more holes that plastic on them). They don't protect you at hits over 20 kmh, speed you can reach with a fart.

Comment: @kifli Because this isn't a question about the effectiveness of helmets. The question states that quite clearly.

Comment: @kifli Yes, helmets do protect the side and back of your head. I've skidded and fallen sideways and backwards while wearing a helmet. The helmet hit the concrete hard, enough to hear a loud crack! I shudder to think how I would have fared had I not worn a helmet.  A colleague came to work with a bleeding face and black eye. He slipped and fell in the rain at exactly the same location where it happened to me. My head was okay in that incident thanks to the helmet. I also had a 20 cm black bruise on my hip that took several days to fully "bloom", and a rib that was sore for 6 months.

Comment: "Motorcyclists use full face helmets because the 'happy biker with bugs on his teeth' experience." I see plenty enough people riding motorbikes with open-face helmets in areas with plenty of bugs.