# Is a chin strap with a cup safer than an under-chin strap?

Tags: safety, helmets, design

Many helmets have **chin straps** to hold them on.

One design uses a **split chin-strap**, where the strap splits into two forming a cup shape, one going just below the lower lip and one under the chin.

[image: Original file public domain https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ACH_005.jpg edited to focus on the chin cup strap]

In my opinion, this is a more comfortable design as the **chin strap** is against the chin bone instead of pressing against the fleshy underside of the lower jaw.

[image: OP's work, from https://i.imgur.com/70lEdtX]

I found a single link http://www.usyouthsports.org/images/CPSC_Hangman_s_4_point_chin_strap.pdf which claims that this design is safer for bike helmets as it may reduce some cases of strangulation in case a "yanking" force is applied to the helmet.

- Were there any other studies done on **chin strap** design like this for bike helmets?
- Is this design safer?
- Are there any bike helmets actually available with this **chin strap** ?

Comment: How are people able to talk or yawn if the chin is pulled up by the chin cup? What’s the reason for the chin cup in the first place? Even climbing helmets have normal straps despite much higher risk of strangulation or the like.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but a lot of the "military helmet for cycling" points were already raised in https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10489/would-a-military-helmet-make-a-safe-alternative-to-a-bicycle-helmet

Comment: The fact that many people wear the helmet far back on the head with often a quite loose chin-strap magnifies the risk of the head being yanked backwards in a fall.

Comment: Can a helmet strap actually strangle you? I imagine you’d rip the anchors out of the helmet before that happens.

Comment: @MaplePanda I found these after a cursory google search https://www.cyclehelmets.org/1227.html and https://helmets.org/playgrou.htm
The cases are rare, though there are indications that this is a possibility (atleast during some non-cycling activities wearing the helmet)

Comment: @MaplePanda I also found out this report https://helmets.org/chinstrp.pdf which establishes the release force of current helmet straps at >1000N which did not release during any of their tests.

Comment: @Michael The lower jaw "hinge point" is near the ear, which would indicate that the actual "lengthwise" change of the strap while talking is fairly low. IMO, it's more difficult to move the jaw in current under-chin designs as the strap directly impedes vertical motion. Also, soldiers do need to talk / shout at each other during combat, so I assume the military has considered this aspect of the design in great detail.

Comment: @user80551: But that’s exactly my point. Under-chin straps are close to the “hinge point” so should need very little slack while the tip of the chin moves the furthest. I’ve never worn such a chin-cup strap helmet, I’d be very interested in how they manage to keep the cup in place.

Comment: The "purpose" of the harness is so when you hang a few pounds of optical equipment off the front of the helmet it doesn't pitch forward and dig a regular chin strap into your neck.  The front of the chin is connected to the strap across the nap of the neck for stability/prevent that strap from riding up.

Comment: I've tried to move this question away from the military and aim it at the chinstrap design.   Feel free to revert or edit further to improve the question.

Comment: @Michael Maybe this (crappily made) illustration will help https://imgur.com/70lEdtX

Comment: @Criggie The rewording is much better, but maybe a little less blur around the cup showing the "right under the lower lip" concept would have been better. The current image doesn't illustrate the positioning of the strap easily IMO.

Comment: @user80551 When I crash my current helmet, I’ll give it a try. Those links are quite scary though.

Answer (score 1):

I've been a motorcyclist for over 50 years and have seen fads come and go.
One was chin cups/straps (early '70's).
A lot of research went into this.
Bottom line is, if you want a helmet to stay where it belongs (on your head) then a properly fitted neck strap is the way to go.
Of course there were all the arguments pro and con, as we see here.
Check out any motorcycle helmet; MotoGP riders rely on this when they're jumping off at 200mph+.
Remember, if you hit something hard enough, no matter what you're wearing, it's going to hurt. Possibly kill you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  You claim that a neck strap is better; do you have any references to support this?  Answers are good, but answers with evidence are better.

Comment: https://www.theukrules.co.uk/rules/driving/highway-code/motorcyclists/helmet-regulations.html(b) If worn with a chin cup attached to or held in position by a strap, is provided with an additional strap (to be fastened under the wearer's jaw) for securing the helmet to the head; and
(c) Is securely fastened to the head by means of straps provided for that purpose; and
'strap' includes any fastening device. Clearly a chin cup type alone is regarded as being inadequate and the main means of securing the helmet is a strap UNDER the chin. Here a chin cup alone is illegal.

Answer (score -4):

Helmet strap will strangle kids, there are cases of children in play grounds not being able to get out.
I would add the magnetic buckle as the solution to these problems. e.g.
https://www.fidlock.com/en/helmet-buckles

Comment: Note the question is about chinstraps with cups, which are in part intended to keep the strap out of the neck.   A breakaway clip is only tangentially related to the point of the question.

Comment: A breakaway chin strap could easily lead to the helmet coming off during a crash. Sure, it _might_ hold for the initial impact, but if you slide along the ground and the helmet comes off, well, that's your ear grinding off against the pavement. Not a lot of fun. Tell the kid to not wear his bike helmet on the playground equipment.