# is bicycle helmet actually safe?

Tags: safety, helmets, protection

The bicycle helmets are almost just made by styrofoam and many people use it instead of motorcycle helmet with full protect and plastic,metal parts.the truck can easily crush it and almost helmet are useless,but when we crash the head to the road,a good helmet will slide out and absorb the force that can help us from being broken the skull while a foam helmet just brake out or transmit the energy to our head and spinal.

Comment: A rare downvote from me for a practically incomprehensible question that also fails to take into account the fact that safety can never be absolute

Comment: nothing is absolutely safe but bicycle helmet is absolutely useless?don't you read my question?

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to disagree with you @Lan, the helmets are certainly not useless and serve their purpose just right. I've had my life saved by one, so I can't be in for the radical skeptics.

Comment: And yep! The "foam helmets" don't break, they get compressed and stay intact! People don't spend their money for devices deemed to kill them.

Comment: well,spend on drug will kill you,send on fake fashionable helmet also can get risks and spending clueless can also route you to the grave soon without directly kill.Stay alive and live good,good bye.

Comment: I attempted to read your question but it didn't make much sense. I share some of your concerns about bike helmets in severe crashes but at low speeds the evidence is good. A

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  All government-certified bike helmets are primarily designed to absorb the force of a fall, and by all accounts they do a good job of this.  (And not even a standard motorcycle helmet will withstand being run over by a truck.)

Comment: Well, it did deserve a flag.

Comment: Daniel R Hicks In the point "they do a good job of this" of you,i have to say that the bicycle helmet is extremely dangerous to wear instead of motorcycle because the ventilating holes of it can allow the objects go through,and the two sides of head aren't protected

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1743/why-dont-cyclists-wear-all-encompassing-motorcycle-style-helmets

Comment: Or: a motorcycle helmet is extremely dangerous to wear because you can't hear what's coming up behind you, and that's important on a bike. Different solutions to different problems.

Comment: VTC as unclear:discussion has made the actual question less, not more, clear.

Comment: Guess what? Neither motorcycle nor bicycle helmets are designed or able to protect you against a truck driving over your head.

Comment: @Lan... And you can sweat like an iron worker in that helmet.

Comment: Paparazzi go to google and type "mũ bảo hiểm xe máy" you will find more type of helmets that save people out of break skull when crash the head to road.

Comment: @Lan... I have helmets thank you.  And I speak English.

Comment: Is this a question or an argument?

Comment: @Lan... Hello and welcome to StackExchange.  Please read the [tour] to learn what is on topic.  Specifically questions should be practical problems that can be answered.    Your question is searching for reasons to not wear a helmet.

Comment: @DanielRHicks "government-certified"? Which government? Which country?

Comment: @owjburnham - US government, unless otherwise noted.

Answer (score 5):

Wearing a bicycle helmet is safer than not wearing one.  Bear in mind that a helmet that has been "crashed" needs to be replaced.  Its ability to absorb/diffuse energy after having been landed on will be degraded.

Answer (score -4):

Personally I never wear a cycle helmet because I find them uncomfortable and I feel that they do impair my ability to be aware of the environment around me. Nonetheless, it is obvious to me that I am putting myself at risk of death or serious injury in certain types of accident where a helmet-wearing cyclist will walk away virtually unscathed.

I know someone who DID have their head run over by a truck whilst wearing a helmet – after much medical care they were fully rehabilitated. I doubt I would have survived the same accident. I expect my organs might have been useful (maybe not the corneas!).

The only way this question can really be answered is with statistics, not opinions. Per 100 cyclists, how many were killed/hospitalised BEFORE helmets became the norm, and how many now? Even then, there are many, many complications, including, but not limited to 1) quantity/type of traffic on the roads 2) quality of brakes on bikes 3) design of road vehicles 4) road design/construction standards 5) type of riding being done 6) age/fitness demographic of typical riders 7) relative availability of cycle paths.

With every type of safety improvement, there are some losers and there are more winners. I know someone who swears that his life was saved by NOT wearing a seat-belt. A steel beam went through the windscreen and through his seat. Luckily he wasn’t in it at the time because he’d been thrown sideways across the passenger seat since he wasn’t retrained by the seat-belt. You’ll always hear these kind of stories, but only the numbers can really tell us whether seat-belts are a POSITIVE or a NEGATIVE overall, and that’s a no-brainer (no pun intended).

Comment: Sampling bias also affects ability to assess real world effectiveness. You crash and hit your head, the helmet does it's job, you don't feel you need to go to the hospital - does this get reported? No. You only tend to see extreme cases in the hospital. These are not necessarily representative.

Comment: @Rider_X That's another very good point.